# How to use xavier weight initializer in chainer

Tags: chainer

I have found this page: https://docs.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/initializers.html

How to use xavier weight initializer to initialize weight in chainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the `xavier` filler of Caffe, `LeCunUniform` and `GlorotUniform` are the corresponding initializers of Chainer (the former uses `fan_in` while the latter uses `(fan_in + fan_out)/2`).